# Multiple bibliographies using natbib and chapterbib: "BibTeX Illegal" error

Tags: bibtex, chapterbib

*This is similar to a previous question, however I cannot find fixes using their answers. MWE code below.* Using Overleaf, I want to include a bibliography at the end of each chapter plus one cohesive bibliography at the end, using the `natbib` package and `plainnat` style. When I compile, I get the intended result, however also the following errors:

[image]

*(Text for copying: "BibTeX Illegal, another \bibstyle command : \bibstyle : {plainnat}", "BibTeX Illegal, another \bibdata command : \bibdata : {References}")*

Even though the output is what I want, I like to be pedantic with my code and deal with any errors if possible. I have already cleared the cached files and refreshed. My minimum working example code is:

**chapter1.tex**

```
\chapter{Title}

Content, including a reference \citep{solopova2014bet}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References}
```

**chapter2.tex**

```
\chapter{Title}

Content, including a reference \citep{godin2010using}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References}
```

**References.bib**

```
@article{solopova2014bet,
  title={Bet-hedging during bacterial diauxic shift},
  author={Solopova, Ana and van Gestel, Jordi and Weissing, Franz J and Bachmann, Herwig and Teusink, Bas and Kok, Jan and Kuipers, Oscar P},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={111},
  number={20},
  pages={7427--7432},
  year={2014},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}

@article{godin2010using,
  title={Using buoyant mass to measure the growth of single cells},
  author={Godin, Michel and Delgado, Francisco Feij{\'o} and Son, Sungmin and Grover, William H and Bryan, Andrea K and Tzur, Amit and Jorgensen, Paul and Payer, Kris and Grossman, Alan D and Kirschner, Marc W and others},
  journal={Nature methods},
  volume={7},
  number={5},
  pages={387--390},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

**Thesis.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]*

This isn't specific to Overleaf; compiling your MWE files on a local computer would also yield the same error messages. When using `chapterbib`, there's usually no "global bibliography" so the `\bibliography{References}` in Thesis.tex would cause problems: see item #2 in "Usage, Restrictions, and Options" section of the [`chapterbib` package documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chapterbib).

You may want to use the `bibunits` package instead, which has an option to also list "local" citations in a "global" reference list.

1. Load `bibunits` with the `globalcitecopy` option to add an entry to the *global* bibliography as well. If you are using the same `.bib` file and the same bibliography style for all units, you can use `\defaultbibliography{...}` and `\defaultbibliographystyle{...}` to specify them.
2. Use `\bibliographyunit[\chapter]` to activate each `\chapter` as a local bibliography unit. Within each `\include` file containing the chapter, use `\putbib` to insert the local bibliography/reference list.
3. For the "global" bibliography in the root `Thesis.tex` file: use the usual `\bibliographystyle{...}` and `\bibliography{...}`.

Here are the sample `Thesis.tex` and `chapter1.tex` files (`chapter2.tex` would be similar).

#### Thesis.tex

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[globalcitecopy]{bibunits}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plainnat}
\defaultbibliography{References}

\begin{document}
\bibliographyunit[\chapter]

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

#### chapter1.tex (similarly chapter2.tex)

```
\chapter{Title}

Content, including a reference \citep{solopova2014bet}.

\putbib
```

Comment: Clear explanation and it works perfectly, thank you! (And sorry for such a late reply - classic thesis-avoidance)

Comment: Actually, this is discussed specifically in item 7 of the usage.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in item 7 of the chapterbib usage, where it is recommended to use

```
\usepackage[rootbib]{chapterbib}
```

for the first run of latex+bibtex if the error/warning messages from bibtex are a problem.

I can't say what Overleaf is using in its build process, but I recall latexmk has or had trouble with seeing the errors. Since version 4.70a, latexmk is supposed to handle it.

Hmmm. It might be useful to have chapterbib accept a "rootbib" option directly from the latex command line, rather than placing pass-options-to-package declarations in the command line ... if that even works.